# Easy way to crypt Model and Key for filename?

Tags: php, laravel, base64, encode

I have many Models in larval (News, Events, Comments...).

I'll link files to the Models. I would like to have filenames like this:

```
testfile-news:1.jpg
```

but the model and key must be encode like this:

```
testfile-Hju2dJmcs3.jpg
```

bas64_encode doesn't work, the filename is to long, and '+/=' aren't compatible for urls.

have anyone an idea?

Comment: You could use something like bin2hex instead of base64 ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Comment: Thats good, thank you well!